# Parsing a JSON string nested in a form-urlencoded POST

Tags: json, forms, go

I'm trying to parse part of the Mailgun notify webhook.
It's a POST request with a `x-www-form-urlencoded` body.
Here's part of the body:

```
sender: some@email.com
attachments: [{"url": "https://storage.eu.mailgun.net/v3/domains/beep.boop/messages/randomstring/attachments/0", "content-type": "application/pdf", "name": "example.pdf", "size": 345}]"]
```

The `attachments` value is a `json` encoded array

I would like to decode this string from JSON to a `StoredAttachment` nested struct as I am decoding the response as `x-www-form-urlencoded` but I don't know how to do it. The target `structs` are as follow:

```golang
type NotifiedMessage struct {
    Sender      string `schema:"sender"`
    Subject     string `schema:"subject"`
    Attachments []StoredAttachment `schema:"attachments"`
    MessageUrl  string `schema:"message-url"`
}

// StoredAttachment structures contain information on an attachment associated with a stored message.
type StoredAttachment struct {
    Size        int    `json:"size"`
    Url         string `json:"url"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    ContentType string `json:"content-type"`
}
```

Here is my non-working code so far: https://play.golang.org/p/Ofbw2VAYV28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `TextUnmarshaler` interface, the `schema` package will use that interface instead of executing the default procedure and this allows for custom unmarshaling.

---

**1.** Declare a *named* type and use that as the type of the `Attachments` field. `[]StoredAttachment` is unnamed. So, for example:

```
type AttachmentList []StoredAttachment
```

Why? Because *methods* can be declared only on named types.

**2.** Implement `TextUnmarhsaler` interface and do the json unmashaling there.

```
func (ls *AttachmentList) UnmarshalText(text []byte) (err error) {
    return json.Unmarshal(text, (*[]StoredAttachment)(ls))
}
```

That's it.

https://play.golang.org/p/t65mI7JRFfS

Comment: amazing thanks. I had tried the `TextUnmarshaler` interface but didn't know about this named type constraint.